# Postgres SQL query com relações de tabelas

Tags: postgresql

Tenho uma tabela users com os seguintes campos:

```
id  
username
email
password
created_at
updated_at
```

Uma tabela followings com os campos :

```
id
user_id 
contact_id  
created_at  
updated_at
```

E uma tabela com os campos:

```
id  
user_id 
content 
created_at  
updated_at
```

Onde Usuários relaciona com a tabela tweets, e a tabela followings, de maneira que um usuário pode ter vários tweets, e um usuário pode ter vários followings.
Vamos supor que tenho um usuário com

> id = 1

e esse usuário tem followings com

> contact_id = 2

e

> contact_id = 3

contact_id seria quem ele está seguindo, nesse caso o

> user_id

da tabela followings seria igual a

> 1

para as duas linhas.
Os usuários 2 e 3, cada um tem alguns tweets, portanto, a dúvida é, como faria para buscar os tweets onde foram postados pelos usuários que estão dentro da minha tabela de followings? como seria a query de consulta para tal?

Answer (score 0):

Supondo que sua última tabela seja a tabela `tweets`, pelo que entendi de sua dúvida:

```
SELECT * FROM folowings INNER JOIN tweets ON folowings.contact_id = tweets.user_id;
```

Caso tenha entendido errado sua dúvida então explique-a melhor.

Comment: Mas onde teria que passar o id do usuário em que quero os tweets dos meus followings?

Comment: Se o que deseja são os dados específicos de um, ou mais de um, usuário então acrescente uma cláusula `WHERE id_user = usuário_desejado`. Mas certamente não dá para depreender que deseja isto com o que você colocou em sua pergunta.

Comment: Resumindo , eu sou o usuario 1, e quero buscar os tweets de todos os usuarios que estão no meu following, vamos supor, tenho os usuarios 2 e 3 no meu following, daí se fosse buscar manualmente ,faria select * from tweets where user_id in (2,3); mas queria fazer isso automaticamente. tipo select * from tweets where user_id in (todos os meus followings); mas não queria buscar primeiro meus followings pra depois pesquisar seus tweets. queria fazer uma query só

Comment: É só utilizar o operador JOIN.